# c program taking multiple inputs instead of one input

Tags: c, scanf

The following code takes two inputs instead of one. The number entered first is stored in n, and the second number is discarded.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int n;
printf("%s\n","Enter a number " );
scanf("%d\n",&n );
printf("Value of n is %d\n",n );
return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Enter a number 
3
5
Value of n is 3
```

Why is it asking for the second input if I have just one `scanf()` in my code?

Comment: why do you add `\n` in your `scanf`?

Comment: Remove the `\n` from scanf call. Unrelated: `printf("%s\n","Enter a number " );` can be written as `printf("Enter a number\n" );`.

Comment: Ohh silly mistake, thank you guys